# C++ Exception Calls _exit

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I have a class that I developed using exceptions. But every time I call a function and it generates an exception, the program appears to hang. Closer investigation shows that the throw command has a long list of calls that eventually calls `exit()`.

```
throw command -> __cxa_throw() -> std::terminate() -> __cxabiv1::__terminate() -> abort() -> _exit()
```

I have used this same method numerous times before so I'm pretty confident that the problem is not in the implementation, but I'm struggling with locating the root cause.  I have also tried a general catch all (...) and I am certain that this is being claled only form one location. Any suggestions?

`Source of the exception (_connectTcp())`:

```
status = nxd_tcp_client_socket_connect(
      socket_ptr,
      &server_addr,
      port,
      wait_option);
if( status != NX_SUCCESS)
{
   throw ERRORS::TCP_SOCKET_BIND_ERROR;
}
```

Try/Catch Block

```
try
{
   _connectTcp( socket_ptr, ip_addr, port, connect_wait);
}
catch( ERRORS err)
{
   error = err;
}
```

Copy of stack:

```
_exit() at _exit.c:19 0x60040b36 abort() at 0x60034da4
__cxxabiv1::__terminate() at 0x60035604 std::terminate() at 0x60035612
__cxa_throw() at 0x60035752 RtController_Ethernet::_connectTcp() at RTController_Ethernet.cpp:1,063 0x6000945c
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Obviously your `catch` does not catch the exception. Please provide a [mcve]. A simple main with throw and try-catch and the necessary types would be sufficient.